# Identify a row alternating color

Tags: php

Sorry about the title I really couldn't figure out how to describe my problem in such short words

So I have this page where I display ranks.

Right now I got it down so it loops the rank name only once. Only problem I have now is making each TR block *where a new rank starts* a diffrent color. I wanna alternate between red and blue.

I'd want the Leader block to be blue, the vice block red and so on, third then blue and so on.

```
_____________

Leader: | Bob
        | Rob
_____________

Vice:   | Jim
        | John
        | Robert
        | Samuel
        | Joe
_____________

Novice: | Sarah
        | Cletus
        | Tom
_____________



$lastRankID = -1;

<?php foreach($db->query($sql) as $row): ?>
<tr bgcolor=" RED/BLUE ">
<td>
<?php if ($lastRankID <> $rankid) echo $rankname; $lastRankID = $rankid; ?>
</td>

<td><?php echo $name ?></td>
</tr>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

This:

```
$i = 0;

<?=($i = !$i) ? 'blue' : 'red'?>

$i++;
```

will ofcourse not work, I dont wanna have diffrent row color on every TR only where a new rank starts.

Any tips for a noob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$colors = array('red', 'blue');
$curcolor = 0;

...

if ($lastRankID != $rankid) {
    $curcolor = ($curcolor+1) % count($colors);
    $lastRankID = $rankid;
}
echo "<TR class='{$colors[$curcolor]}'>";
```